# Comma-separated values (CSV) parameter filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, csv

Need help on how to improve my SQL script for better performance. `dbo.Products` table has a million rows. I'm hesitant to rewrite it using dynamic SQL. Thanks!

```
DECLARE
    @Brand varchar(MAX) = 'Brand 1, Brand 2, Brand 3',
    @ItemCategory varchar(MAX) = 'IC1, IC2, IC3, IC4, IC5'

--will return all records if params where set to @Brand = NULL, @ItemCategory = NULL

SELECT
     [Brand],
     SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount] 
FROM dbo.Products (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Split](@Brand, ',') FilterBrand ON Brand = [FilterBrand].[Items]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Split](@ItemCategory, ',') FilterItemCategory ON ItemCategory = [FilterItemCategory].[Items] 
WHERE
    (@Brand IS NULL OR (@Brand IS NOT NULL AND [FilterBrand].[Items]  IS NOT NULL)) AND
    (@ItemCategory IS NULL OR (@ItemCategory IS NOT NULL AND [FilterItemCategory].[Items] IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY
     [Brand]
```

Below is the split table-valued function that I found on the web:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String     varchar(8000),
    @Delimiter  char(1)
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Items varchar(4000))
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@String IS NULL OR @String = '') RETURN

    DECLARE @i int, @j int

    SELECT @i = 1

    WHILE @i <= LEN(@String)
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @j = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @i)

            IF @j = 0
                BEGIN
                    SELECT  @j = len(@String) + 1
                END

            INSERT  @Results SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, @i, @j - @i))

            SELECT  @i = @j + LEN(@Delimiter)
        END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Few things: (1) do you **really** need **ALL** columns from `Products`? If not - please don't use `SELECT *` but instead specify a list of columns explicitly. This *might* open an up an opportunity for performance tuning; (2) make sure all the columns involved in the `JOIN`s are properly indexed;

Comment: I have recently documented some much more efficient approaches to splitting strings: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings & http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up

Comment: @marc_s I modified my sample script. I'm not using "SELECT *" in real life... Thanks.

Comment: @AaronBertrand wow thanks, will try your recommendations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following solution are with out using functions

```
Declare @IDs Varchar(100)
SET @IDs = '2,4,6'

Select IsNull(STUFF((Select ', '+ CAST([Name] As Varchar(100)) From [TableName]
Where CharIndex(','+Convert(Varchar,[ID])+',', ','+@IDs+',')> 0
For XML Path('')),1,1,''),'') As [ColumnName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use.  I also have another that wraps this to return numeric values which I find helpful as well.

Edit: Sorry, as for how to improve the performance of the query, I usually split the values into table variables and perform my joins to that but that probably won't change your performance, just your readability.  The only thing I can see in terms of performance is your double checking whether your joins produce anything.  You really can't get much better performance with two conditional left joins on two tables.  It basically boils down to indexes at that point.

```
(@Brand IS NULL OR [FilterBrand].[Items] IS NOT NULL)
```

Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitDelimittedList]
(
    @DelimittedList varchar(8000),
    @Delimitter varchar(20)
)
RETURNS 
@List TABLE 
(
    Item varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DelimitterLength INT
    SET @DelimitterLength = LEN(@Delimitter)

    -- Tack on another delimitter so we get the last item properly
    set @DelimittedList = @DelimittedList + @Delimitter

    declare @Position int
    declare @Item varchar(500)

    set @Position = patindex('%' + @Delimitter + '%' , @DelimittedList)
    while (@Position <> 0)
    begin
        set @Position = @Position - 1
        set @Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(left(@DelimittedList, @Position)))

        INSERT INTO @List (Item) VALUES (@Item)

        set @DelimittedList = stuff(@DelimittedList, 1, @Position + @DelimitterLength, '')
        set @Position = patindex('%' + @Delimitter + '%' , @DelimittedList)
    end

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey just try the split function I have created without using any while loops here.And just use this in place of your split function and use col to match in LEFT join.

```
ALTER function dbo.SplitString(@inputStr varchar(1000),@del varchar(5))
RETURNS @table TABLE(col varchar(100))
As
BEGIN

DECLARE @t table(col1 varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t
select @inputStr

if CHARINDEX(@del,@inputStr,1) > 0
BEGIN
;WITH CTE as(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as id,* from @t)
,CTE1 as (
select id,ltrim(rtrim(LEFT(col1,CHARINDEX(@del,col1,1)-1))) as col,RIGHT(col1,LEN(col1)-CHARINDEX(@del,col1,1)) as rem from CTE
union all
select c.id,ltrim(rtrim(LEFT(rem,CHARINDEX(@del,rem,1)-1))) as col,RIGHT(rem,LEN(rem)-CHARINDEX(@del,rem,1))
from CTE1 c
where CHARINDEX(@del,rem,1)>0
)

INSERT INTO @table 
select col from CTE1
union all
select rem from CTE1 where CHARINDEX(@del,rem,1)=0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @table 
select col1 from @t
END


RETURN

END


DECLARE @Brand varchar(MAX) = 'Brand 1,Brand 2,Brand 3',
        @ItemCategory varchar(MAX) = ' IC1 A ,IC2 B , IC3 C, IC4 D' --'IC1, IC2, IC3, IC4, IC5'

select * from dbo.SplitString(@ItemCategory,',')
```

Comment: i tried your split function and its faster than what im using. Problem is if i have this param value: 


DECLARE @ItemCategory varchar(MAX) = ' IC1 A ,IC2 B , IC3 C, IC4 D'

select * from dbo.SplitString(@ItemCategory,',')

OUTPUT:

 IC1 A 
 IC3 C
IC2 B 
IC2 B , IC3 C, IC4 D

Comment: Hey check the latest updated function.I was doing small mistake in the previous while returning the output.So this will work perfectly.

Comment: oops still have an issue. try this DECLARE @ItemCategory varchar(MAX) = 'IC1 A';
select * from dbo.SplitString(@ItemCategory,','); Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: and also this DECLARE @ItemCategory varchar(MAX) = ''; Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: hey try the latest query.Sorry I did not consider few conditions in hurry.